# HTML/Ruby On Rails: Execute redirect automatically?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page with the following code:

```
<div>
  <% if @site.roster_management_enabled? %>
    <h3><%= link_to "Go To Page", { :controller => 'roster_player_import', :action => 'rostering_redirect'}, :target => "_blank" %></h3>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The controller/action mentioned above is as follows:

```
  def rostering_redirect
    url = URI.join(@site.boss_organization.admin_app_root_url, 'rostering')
    redirect_to url.to_s
  end
```

I want the html code listed above to execute automatically rather than having the user click on the link. To be more specific, is there a way to return the URL from the controller/action and pass that to the HTML code such that I don't have to use the syntax `{:controller =>.....}` and instead use something like `URL=....`

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Why don't you just add the `redirect_to` call with the condition to the controller method that renders the view? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Well the user is going to have to click the link but you can replace the hash in link to with `URI.join(@site.boss_organization.admin_app_root_url, 'rostering').to_s`

Comment: @engineersmnky oh just use instead of {:controller =>....}?

Comment: @DeeWBee yes the second argument to [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) can just be a `String`. In your case this `String` will be the Url and will generate an anchor with a href of the URL passed in. e.g. `<a href="[YOUR URL]" target="_blank">Go To Page</a>`. The way you have it now might be more advantageous if you intend to log information about who or when that link was clicked but otherwise just let them click straight through

Answer (score 0):

You can put the url you redirect to directly in your template:

```
<div>
  <% if @site.roster_management_enabled? %>
    <h3><%= link_to 'Go To Page', URI.join(@site.boss_organization.admin_app_root_url, 'rostering').to_s, target: '_blank' %></h3>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This works if:

- `@site` is available in the template (from your code it is not clear where it is loaded)
- You do not need to run additional checks/tracking on the server side